# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer does not detect objects in two ranges of the screen

Tags: swift, xcode, avcapturesession, coreml, apple-vision

I downloaded Apple's project about recognizing Objects in Live Capture.
When I tried the app I saw that if I put the object to recognize on the top or on the bottom of the camera view, the app doesn't recognize the object:

In this first image the banana is in the center of the camera view and the app is able to recognize it.

[image object in center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67jay.jpg)

In these two images the banana is near to the camera view's border and it is not able to recognize the object.

[image object on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1yPf.jpg)

[image object on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlBnV.jpg)

This is how session and previewLayer are set:

```
 func setupAVCapture() {
    var deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

    // Select a video device, make an input
    let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back).devices.first
    do {
        deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!)
    } catch {
        print("Could not create video device input: \(error)")
        return
    }

    session.beginConfiguration()
    session.sessionPreset = .vga640x480 // Model image size is smaller.

    // Add a video input
    guard session.canAddInput(deviceInput) else {
        print("Could not add video device input to the session")
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }
    session.addInput(deviceInput)
    if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
        session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        // Add a video data output
        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)
    } else {
        print("Could not add video data output to the session")
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }
    let captureConnection = videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)
    // Always process the frames
    captureConnection?.isEnabled = true
    do {
        try  videoDevice!.lockForConfiguration()
        let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions((videoDevice?.activeFormat.formatDescription)!)
        bufferSize.width = CGFloat(dimensions.width)
        bufferSize.height = CGFloat(dimensions.height)
        videoDevice!.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    session.commitConfiguration()
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    rootLayer = previewView.layer
    previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds
    rootLayer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
}
```

You can download the project [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture),
I am wondering if it is normal or not.

Is there any solutions to fix?
Does it take square photos to elaborate with coreml and the two ranges are not included? 
Any hints? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because the `imageCropAndScaleOption` is set to `centerCrop`.

The Core ML model expects a square image but the video frames are not square. This can be fixed by setting the `imageCropAndScaleOption` option on the `VNCoreMLRequest`. However, the results may not be as good as with center crop (it depends on how the model was originally trained).

See also `VNImageCropAndScaleOption` in the Apple docs.